# Region server geting down frequently after system start

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am running hbase on HDP on Amazon machine,

When i reboot my system and start all hbase  services, it get started.

But after some time my region server get down.

Latest error that i am getting from its log file is that

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /apps/hbase/data/usertable/dd5a251551619e0109349a0dce855e1b/recovered.edits/0000000000000001172.temp could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1657)
```

Now i am not able to start it.

Any suggestion why it is happing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you datanodes are up and running. Also, set "dfs.data.dir" to some permanent location, if you haven't done it yet. It defaults to the "/tmp" dir which gets emptied at each restart. Also, make sure that your datanodes are able to talk to the namenode and there is no network related issue and the datanode machines have enough free space left.

Comment: my data node is up and it data directory not in tmp folder

Comment: do you have free space there?

Comment: Actually my EBS of detached , that's why it was getting down again and again.

Comment: yeah..that was my point..while working with AWS make sure restarting AMIs will cause that problem.